# Adding a new nodegroup to AWS EKS cluster results in IPv4 Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, amazon-eks

I have an existing AWS EKS cluster with 3 Amazon Linux 2 nodes and 3 Windows Server 2019 nodes. I have a docker image that must be run on a 20H2 container so, I am trying to add a new node group with a WindowsServer20H2CoreContainer. However, when adding the new node group after already having the EKS cluster created it always results in the following error when trying to create a pod...

network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address

This happened to me previously when I created the cluster with just 3 Linux nodes originally and I tried adding the 3 Windows Server 2019 nodes. I ended up deleting the cluster and then adding the 3 Windows Server 2019 nodes from creation. Which resolved the issue... I could simply do that with this node but I would like to find a solution to this error because deleting a cluster to add a new node is simply not a viable solution.

The following is my yaml for the new node group:

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: POCK8sCluster
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.21"

availabilityZones: ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]

nodeGroups:
- name: mal-ng
  amiFamily: WindowsServer20H2CoreContainer
  desiredCapacity: 1
  instanceType: t3.small
  ssh:
    enableSsm: true

secretsEncryption:
  keyARN: redacted
```